# Function returns None, but prints result

Tags: python

```
def maximum(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr[0]
    else:
        if arr[0] > arr[1]:
            del arr[1]
            maximum(arr)
        elif arr[0] <= arr[1]:
            del arr[0]
            maximum(arr)


print(maximum([2, 2]))
```

If I change `return arr[0]` with `print(arr[0])` it prints out 2, but for some reason it returns None if I write `return arr[0]`. I also tried returning the whole array as the array is always 1 element long, but that didn't change anything and still returns None.

Comment: Every path of execution must end in a `return`; unless the implicit `None` return is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return your recursive calls

```
def maximum(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr[0]
    else:
        if arr[0] > arr[1]:
            del arr[1]
            return maximum(arr)
    elif arr[0] <= arr[1]:
        del arr[0]
        return maximum(arr)
```